Regular expression for finding a function call
I'm trying to find all calls to a function $t
I tried this expression
/\$t\([^)]+\)/g
but this does not work if I have a ) in the string like so
$t('Name (optional)')

other possible complex values can be
$t('hello' + x)
$t("hello"  + x)
$t(`hello ${x}`)
$t(x)

I assume I need a lookbehind?
Thank you

It can be even worse, like $t('Name - no ) allowed!')

Add to that the fact that functions can be called without parentheses, and you'll be ready to give up.

It's pretty much impossible to use a regex that doesn't support recursion/balanced groups (such as JavaScript) to match deep nested/paired of anything: $t('Name (optional)' + ((1 + 2) * 3) + 'Bob\'s Bar')

This almost works, but you can't have nested parenthesis in the function call.

Ok, For anyone in this position, this was my solution
I used this expression /\$t\(.*/gm to find all places where $t is called,
then I split m.split('$t(') (in case $t is called more then once on that line),
then looped over results and parsed the string with acorn-loose (a javascript parser/tokenizer),
then found 1st call expression and handled arguments individually (strings, variables, etc) via switch.
example
import * as acorn from 'acorn-loose';

const string = `
$t()
$t(x)
$t('hello' + x)
$t("hello" + x)
$t(\`hello \${x}\`)
$t(x) + $t(x)
$t('Name (optional)')
$t('Bob\\'s Bar') $t('Bob\\'s Bar')
`;

/** @param nodes {Array<import('acorn/dist/acorn').Node>} */
function getFirstCallExpression(nodes) {
    for (const node of nodes) {
        if (node.type === 'CallExpression') return node;
        else if (node.left) return getFirstCallExpression([node.left]);
        else if (node.expression) return getFirstCallExpression([node.expression]);
        else if (node.expressions) return getFirstCallExpression(node.expressions);
    }
    return false;
}

let strings = [], odd = [];

for (const m of string.matchAll(/\$t\(.*/gm)) {
    for (let i of m[0].split('$t(').filter(v => v.trim())) {
        i = '$t(' + i;
        let p = acorn.parse(i);
        const node = getFirstCallExpression(p.body);

        if (!node) {
            odd.push(i);
            continue;
        }

        if (node.callee.name !== '$t') {
            odd.push(i);
            continue;
        }

        let arg = node.arguments[0];

        switch (arg.type) {
            case 'Literal':
                strings.push(arg.value);
                break;
            case 'TemplateLiteral':
                if (arg.expressions.length === 0) {
                    strings.push(arg.quasis[0].value.cooked);
                } else odd.push(i);
                break;
            default:
                odd.push(i);
                break;
        }
    }
}

console.log(strings);
console.log(odd);



